# Eclipse Force.com IDE Warnings - "Refresh Error"

Tags: ide, eclipse, connected-apps

When connected to my Salesforce Sandbox / Dev Org I get the following errors:

[image: Refresh error: Metadata API received improper input. PLease ensure file name and capitalisation are correct. Load of metadata from db failed for metadata of type: xxx and filename: yyy]

<del>Looking at the actual package file it seems like there aren't any references to these ConnectedApps (Eg Chatter_desktop, Dataloader_Bulk and so on)</del>

<del>Is Force.com IDE expecting to see these references?</del>

*Edit: Ah I see there's a package.xml for each referenced package. Eg this is the package.xml for Chatter Desktop:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <fullName>Chatter_Desktop</fullName>
    <apiAccessLevel>Unrestricted</apiAccessLevel>
    <namespacePrefix>sf_chttr_apps</namespacePrefix>
    <types>
        <members>Chatter_Desktop</members>
        <name>Application</name>
    </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>
```

I've noticed that if I go to a sandbox org webpage and go to

Administration Setup > Manage Apps > Connected Apps

And then click edit on any of the apps I get an Internal Server error. Never good.

I've seen this with every sandbox/dev org I've created. It doesn't seem to cause me any problems, but can anyone explain what these warnings mean?

Comment: Force.com IDE seems to be updated recently, and it fixed some package.xml related issues, see if that helps : https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2013/09/updated-force-com-ide-plugin-available-more-on-the-way.html

Comment: "No updates found". I'm using Force.com IDE 30.0.0.201404021749, which I'm guessing was turned out on the 2nd April 2014.